# How can send diameter commands in two sessions

Tags: linux, network-programming, traffic, diameter-protocol

Hi i'm designing a seagull scenario look like:

Client    --------------- Server
    --- `CER` -->
    <-- `CEA` ---
               --- `AAR` --> // the first session
               <-- `AAA` ---
               --- `AAR` -->
               <-- `AAA` --
               <-- `RAR` --
               --- `RAA` -->
               --- `STR` -->
               <-- `STA` --
               --- `AAR` -->  // the second session
               <-- `AAA` --
               <-- `RAR` --
               --- `RAA` -->
               --- `STR` -->
    <-- `STA` --

But in the second call, we saw an message in log "Expected AAR when receiving RAA.." . If we make the second call scenario same as the first call, (two AAR\AAA and one RAR/RAA)
it was passed.

So that the question is " Is there any ways to control seagull flow as the scenario that we expected? "

Thanks,

Tran.

Answer (score 0):

When you run seagull there is a scenario that is sending or waiting for specific messages. 
seagull can only send or accept the messages that are defined in the scenario. All other message will create an error.

Looks like your seagull  scenario (on the server side) is waiting to receive twice AAR.
When it receives RAR instead of the second AAR it generates this error.